# I need help. How to group array by date using laravel eloquent and foreach loop?

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, eloquent, laravel-8

Hello i have trouble in grouping array in laravel foreach. I have an array result like this [image: My Sample Array] coming from laravel eloquent groupby(['date', 'project_site_id']). now my expected output is all date that is under that date will be combined [image: Expected sample output]. Below is my code.

```
$current_date = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d'));

$data = EmployeeActivities::where('date', '>=', $current_date->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('date', '<=', $current_date->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(['date', 'project_site_id']);

foreach($data as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $key_nested){
        echo $key.' '.$key_nested.'</br></br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the group by clause `groupBy(['date', 'project_site_id'])` results are showing fine because for date `2021-02-01` there are 2 rows with different `project_site_id`s so that is why they are separated. If you want to group the collection only by date then remove `project_site_id` from grouping criteria

```
$data = EmployeeActivities::where('date', '>=', $current_date->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'))
                          ->where('date', '<=', $current_date->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'))
                          ->get()
                          ->groupBy(['date']);
```